# Dimensional regularization and (dimension) compactification

Tags: quantum-field-theory, regularization, compactification, dimensional-regularization

I believe I read that "additional dimension" in dimensional regularization can be understood as spatial dimensions compactified, but I could not find resources related to this.

Is this view correct? And if so, can anyone elaborate on this view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dimensional regularization has nothing to do with compactified dimensions, or at least it didn’t when I learned quantum field theory. The $d$ dimensions in dimensional regularization are all infinite in extent and spacetime remains flat. Integrals which are divergent for $d=4$ are typically finite in *fewer* dimensions; they can then be analytically continued to arbitrary (even non-integral) $d$, making divergences appear as terms involving $1/(d-4)$.